# max length in CKEditor plugin

Tags: html, grails, groovy, ckeditor, fckeditor

I'm using plugin ckeditor in grails 2.4.3, latest version.

However, I cannot find option to set max length in this editor.

Any helps would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

No such option exists. Part of the problem is that it is too hard to measure what constitutes max length for different sites. You must build your own solution based on your requirements on what "max length" means for you.

Sometimes user want the text to not contain more than N chars, sometimes the source must not be longer than M characters and sometimes the content must not exceed a certain graphical boundary (height/width) - it all depends.